# max(count(*)) error: how to find max of count function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select room_id, count(distinct course_code) 
from "LearningActivity"  
group by room_id
```

[image]

i only need the max of the count(distinct course_code). In the photo you see in the output that we have 3 rows and i want to show only the maximum of the count which is the 3rd row with `count=3`. Any ideas will help because i tried to put `max(count(distinct course_code)` but i get the error `aggregate function calls cannot be nested`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `LIMIT` here:

```
SELECT room_id, COUNT(DISTINCT course_code) 
FROM LearningActivity
GROUP BY room_id
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT course_code) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This would return the `room_id` and its count corresponding to the room with the highest distinct count.

For a more general solution which would capture all rooms with the highest distinct course count, should there be 2 or more which are tied, use `RANK`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT room_id, COUNT(DISTINCT course_code) AS cnt,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT course_code) DESC) rnk
    FROM LearningActivity
    GROUP BY room_id
)

SELECT room_id, cnt
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: it woulld work for this example but if i insert more entries there could be more than one room_id with maximum count.. very smart though!! Can it be modified in a where clause and with a variable that saves the COUNT(DISTINCT course_code) DESC
LIMIT 1 and after in the where clause checks all rooms with that count?

Comment: I tested it mutiple times and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot my friend!!!